# how to get scope with self reference in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end
```

I want to a Scope with select all Category in tables categories with  `category.children == nil` or `(category.children.count == 0)`.

Pls help me.

Answer (score 3):

```
scope :no_children, -> { includes(:children).where(children: { id: nil }) }
```

or

```
scope :without_children, { where('not exists (select null from children where children.parent_id = category.id)') }
```